# memsql_platform.network.state.primary_state.primary_poll: Failed to lookup local agent

Tags: singlestore

I am trying to install MemSQL 4.1.7 on a RHEL 6 machine in offline mode following the instructions:
http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/offline/

In step 3, memsql-ops start command completes with the following error message

```
    memsql-ops-4.1.7 > memsql-ops/memsql-ops start
    Starting MemSQL Ops...
    Exception in thread Thread-7:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 869, in run
    File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/daemon/manage.py", line 198, in startup_watcher
    File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/network/api_client.py", line 32, in call
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 501, in loads
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

After that I can access the MemSQL Ops web interface and it complains "MemSQL Ops is unable to connect to the MemSQL download servers" and prompts me to add the binaries. Hence I followed step 5 of the instruction guide and got this error

```
    memsql-ops > memsql-ops file-add -t memsql memsqlbin_amd64.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    File "/memsql_platform/bin/memsql-ops", line 18, in <module>
    File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/cli/client.py", line 197, in parse
    File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/cli/command_file_add.py", line 27, in run
    File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/agent/cli/file_add_mixin.py", line 58, in add_file
    File "/memsql_platform/memsql_platform/network/api_client.py", line 32, in call
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 501, in loads
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    File "/usr/local/updated-openssl/lib/python3.4/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

=====================================

This is the memsql-ops.log

```
2015-10-19 17:05:37,667 [INFO] memsql_platform.agent.daemon.daemon: Binding to xx.xx.xx.xx:9000
2015-10-19 17:05:38,458 [INFO] memsql_platform.network.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,462 [ERROR] memsql_platform.network.state.primary_state.primary_poll: Failed to lookup local agent
2015-10-19 17:05:38,483 [INFO] memsql_platform.analytics.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,505 [INFO] memsql_platform.topology.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,509 [INFO] memsql_platform.spark.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,518 [INFO] memsql_platform.user_intent.intention_manager: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,521 [INFO] memsql_platform.user_intent.intention_manager: Checking 1 active intentions
2015-10-19 17:05:38,533 [INFO] memsql_platform.usage_statistics.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,537 [INFO] memsql_platform.benchmark.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,551 [INFO] memsql_platform.cluster.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,580 [INFO] memsql_platform.files.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,632 [INFO] memsql_platform.jobs.engine: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:38,636 [INFO] memsql_platform.jobs.job_requeuer: Ready.
2015-10-19 17:05:42,974 [INFO] memsql_platform.network.web_socket_handler: Received websocket connection from xx.xx.xx.xx
2015-10-19 17:13:03,553 [INFO] memsql_platform.network.web_socket_handler: Closed websocket connection with xx.xx.xx.xx due to [1001] None
2015-10-19 17:13:03,573 [INFO] memsql_platform.network.web_server: 304 GET / (xx.xx.xx.xx) 1.19ms
2015-10-19 17:13:03,895 [INFO] memsql_platform.network.web_socket_handler: Received websocket connection from xx.xx.xx.xx
2015-10-19 17:13:18,714 [INFO] memsql_platform.network.web_socket_handler: Closed websocket connection with xx.xx.xx.xx due to [1001] None
```

Can anyone confirm if MemSQL 4.1.7 works with RHEL 6 or does it require some other dependencies?

Comment: The MemSQL Ops command line works by sending API requests to http://127.0.0.1:9000.  When you visit the web UI, it uses the same API, but it sends requests to http://<the hostname of your server>:9000.  So the fact that the web UI works but not the command line indicates that you probably have something running on your machine that's using 127.0.0.1.  What's the output of `curl -X POST -i 127.0.0.1:9000/api/v1/ping`?  How about `curl -X POST -i <the IP address of your server>:9000/api/v1/ping`?

Comment: curl -X POST -i 127.0.0.1:9000/api/v1/ping  gives me an "Access Denied" page and  
curl -X POST -i <the IP address of your server>:9000/api/v1/ping gives me "pong"
Do I have to specify the --host when I do memsql-ops start ??

Comment: It's likely that you're running some other program that's using port 9000.  Do you have any web servers or anything else running on this machine?

Comment: Yes there are webservers  running on the machine but they are independent of the port 9000. I did a netstat -tulpn and verified it.

Comment: Well, you should figure out what process is creating the Access Denied page that you're seeing and try to shut it down.  Clearly, something is producing that output, so once you track it down you should be able to stop it.

You can also try starting up MemSQL Ops on a different port with `memsql-ops start --port 9001`.

Comment: @WayneSong I did ` export no_proxy=127.0.0.1 ` and now it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Wayne Song in the comments. The MemSQL Ops command line works by sending API requests to 127.0.0.1:9000

So if your server is inside a corporate firewall there is a possibility that the request to 127.0.0.1 may not pass. So adding 127.0.0.1 to no_proxy solved this problem.

you can set this in command line as:

```
export no_proxy=127.0.0.1
```